# html canvas returning line not connecting

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying out a simple script to create a rectangle and it seemed to work find except that the final leg of the polygon doesn't connect with the first leg properly. The strange thing is that all the other legs do connect properly.

Before anyone suggests that I use the built-in drawRect() or similar function, I should emphasize that this is just a simple example of a far more complex figure I'm trying to draw. I'm just confused why this is happening.

```
newX = 10;
letterHeight = 100;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#999999";
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.moveTo(newX,letterHeight*0.5);
ctx.lineTo(newX+letterWidth,letterHeight*0.5);
ctx.lineTo(newX+letterWidth,letterHeight);
ctx.lineTo(newX, letterHeight);
ctx.lineTo(newX, letterHeight*0.5);
ctx.stroke();
```

It seems to me that this probably has something to do with the line width and I could consider some problem-specific crude fix for that but is there a more general fix if that's the case?

[Link to how the script rendered (using firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8slEq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ctx.closePath();` just before the stroke command to close the path. You should also be starting the path with `ctx.beginPath();`

Comment: Thanks, I see that that works and I've accepted your answer but what if I'm drawing two figures, one of which is open-ended (like the letter "U") but the other figure is closed (like a rectangle). How can I draw both such that their base is on the same visual level.

Comment: If you want one closed and the other open don't include the closePath command for the open one. You will have to add a separate stroke command for each shape.

Comment: I understand that the closePath should only be used, well, to close the path but the problem is that drawing two lines of the same length programmatically renders two lines of different lengths visually if one path is closed and the other is not. I can think of a crude solution but I was wondering if there was a more principled approach. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: If you are getting different sizes make sure the open lines are capped correctly `ctx.lineCap("butt")` will ensure the line is the correct length, having the cap as "round" or "square" will add half the line width to each end of the line making it longer. Also `ctx.lineJoin()`, `ctx.miterLimit()`, and `ctx.lineWidth()` effect how strokes are displayed. For more info http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_canvas.asp

Comment: Oops my bad they are not functions they are attributes `ctx.lineCap = "butt"` not `ctx.lineCap("butt");` same for the others.. Sorry bout dat..